# SKShapeNode Path not updating

Tags: sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skshapenode

I've created an circle with an UIBezierPath which I add to a SKShapeNode.
The circle displays fine. But when I want to update the path nothing happens. I keep seeing the same initial path I created. Do I have to call some kind of update function for the path to update properly? Color changes and stroke changes work fine but the path remains unchanged.

```swift
 override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    shape = SKShapeNode.init()

    endAngle = CGFloat(endAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    startAngle = CGFloat(startAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0

    let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:0,y:0), radius: 30, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle , clockwise: true)

    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

    shape!.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shape!.fillColor = UIColor.red
    addChild(shape!)

}


func changePath () {
    self.endAngle -= 0.1
    self.circle.path = nil

    let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:0,y:0), radius: 35, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: self.endAngle , clockwise: true)
    self.circle.path = circlePath.cgPath
}
```

Comment: Is the `circle` property the `SKShapeNode` you are referring to? And is this the same as the `shape` `SKShpaeNode` you create in the init?

Comment: aaaargh!! I'm such an idiot. that's exactly what the problem was. I created a temp SKShapeNode and I forgot to change the path on that temp node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `SKShapeNode` you are referring to in your `changePath` function isn't the same an in the initializer above. Updating the path on the correct node should do the trick!